# How to write large numbers of .jpg, .png, etc images to a single file?

Tags: python, computer-vision, parallel-io

I am trying to optimize deep learning computer vision pipelines for HPC architectures that have high performance parallel IO. Storing large numbers of files in a single directory is an anti-pattern on such systems. Much better IO performance will be achieved if I can collect the images and write them into a single large file.

What file formats are best suited for this task? Do Python libraries exist to write large numbers of images files into a single binary file format? I came across [GEIS](http://www.stsci.edu/hst/wfpc2/Wfpc2_dhb/intro_ch24.html) files which look fit for purpose but can not find examples demonstrating usage.

Comment: you could look at hdf5 or lmdb

Comment: I use uncompressed zip for this. It's very simple, widely supported, and there's a zip64 standard for huge files. I use libgsf to write these things and it seems fine, but perhaps there's a better library. libgsf has a Python binding via gobject.